# Editing the age of System Restore point?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, system-restore

Hi all I was wondering why are there contradictory info for the age of a system restore point?

[http://windows.microsoft.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/System-Restore-frequently-asked-questions):

> Restore points are saved until the hard disk space System Restore reserves is filled up. As new restore points are created, old ones are deleted.

[http://support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301224):

> A restore point reaches an age of 90 days. The restore point is then deleted because 90 days is the default time to live.

So who is right?

Also, how do we edit the allowed age of a system restore point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't read [the entire page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301224).

> The deletion of restore points may be caused by ***any*** one of the following by-design conditions:
>
> - **You run out of disk space** on the system drive or on any one of the available non-system drives, and System Restore stops responding and stops monitoring your system. **This behavior causes the system to delete all restore points in an attempt to free up disk space.**
> - ...
> - You are running low on disk space, but not so low that System Restore stops performing. System Restore deletes some of the restore points, but not all of them. This occurs because **System Restore uses a First In First Out (FIFO) process to decrease the size of the data store to approximately 75 percent of its maximum size when the data store reaches approximately 90 percent of its maximum size.** The maximum size may be the default size, or it may be set by the user. System Restore performs this deletion regardless of how much disk space you have.
> - **A restore point reaches an age of 90 days. The restore point is then deleted because 90 days is the default time to live.**

In other words: If you have enough disk space, restore points are kept for a **maximum** of 90 days. But if you're running out of disk space, or if the reserved space limit is being reached, restore points will be deleted **earlier**.

---

Also note that these two pages describe **different operating systems** – Windows Vista and Windows XP/ME respectively (see *Applies to*) – therefore their information cannot be contradictory. (Vista uses a different implementation and does not limit the shadow copy age.)

---

> how do we edit the allowed age of a system restore point?

For Windows XP, the [settings are stored in Registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295659) at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore`. The maximum age of a restore point is kept in the `RPLifeInterval` value, which defaults to 7776000 seconds.

Windows Vista does not have a maximum age limit for shadow copies.

Comment: Heys thanks for the help, btw am I right to say that Windows-7 is like Vista (in that there is no maximum age limit for shadow copies?)

Comment: @Pacerier: [Yes.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/System-Restore-frequently-asked-questions)